# Converting Seq[String] to String*

Tags: string, scala, type-conversion, seq

I have a function that accepts `String*` as parameters. I am implementing another function that takes `Seq[String]` (or an array of string) as a parameter but needs to call the previous function with that parameter. Is there any way to make the conversion?

```
def foo (s: String*) = {
    ...
}

def callFoo (s: Seq[String]) = {
    foo (s)     // this throws an error
}
```

`foo` function can be called as `foo("string1", "string2", "string3")`. But I want to only call `callFoo(Seq[String])` function and get the result from `foo()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can adapt your `Seq` to the variable argument list that `foo` expects using the `_*` operator, as follows:

```
def callFoo (s: Seq[String]) = {
    foo (s: _*)
}
```